# In Chebyshev general solution, why the constants are set to ${0,1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chebyshev-polynomials

Chebyshev DE: $$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+n^2y=0$$

The general solution for the DE is: $$y(t)=C\cos(nt+\alpha)$$

I found that books sets the constants to be: ${C=1, \alpha=0}$

Why we set these values ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Have a look for example at [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevDifferentialEquation.html), in the end all solutions are given as far as I can see. What is the source you are citing?